# Specific part of code not being executed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, image, parse-platform

I am retrieving data from Parse.com and try to add an image with this data to an array. However, some code is not being executed without any obvious reason. This is the code:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:[self.event objectForKey:@"members"]];
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.membersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:users];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

        for (PFUser *user in self.membersArray) {

            [self.memberPhotosArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
            NSInteger index = [self.memberPhotosArray indexOfObject:user];

            PFFile *photoFile = [user objectForKey:@"profilePicture"];

            [photoFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Before creating image");
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
                    [self.memberPhotosArray[index] addObject:image];
                    NSLog(@"After creating image");
                    [self.tableView reloadData];

                }
            }];

        }

    }
}];
```

The first log is being executed, everything after this line is not being called. Can someone explain why and provide a solution?

Comment: You aren't seeing a crash are you? If image is nil when you call [self.memberPhotosArray[index] addObject:image]; it will blow up. Also, I might be wrong, but you may be retaining self in that block.

Comment: I'm not very good at coding but I am using ARC, so shouldn't it do all the retain/release by itself?

Comment: A retain cycle is a loop where objects retain each other mutually. If either object is released:

Object A won't be deallocated because Object B holds a reference to it.
But Object B won't ever be deallocated as long as Object A has a reference to it.
But Object A will never be deallocated because Object B holds a reference to it.
ad infinitum

Comment: I guess I understood, but I doubt I am retaining it. But again, isn't ARC doing all this stuff for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your code is running on a background thread. Run the code in the final callback block on the main thread.

```
if (!error) {
     NSLog(@"Before creating image");
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self.memberPhotosArray[index] addObject:image];
         NSLog(@"After creating image");
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
}
```

UI related operations should only be performed on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, it is executing now! However, when I want to add the object to the array at the given index, the application crashes with the error: [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'. Why is the number so extremely high?

Comment: it is giving a an invalid index. Make you sure you are comparing the right object and `NSInteger index = [self.memberPhotosArray indexOfObject:user];` returns a valid integer.

Comment: I made a spelling mistake, working perfectly now, thanks!